# Why is addition of 1,000,000 floats faster when using a generic wrapper class?

Tags: c#, performance, generics, addition

I have a simple class which provides mathematical operations independent of the numerical type. To simplify my question, I have reduced my classes to the following:

```
public abstract class MathProvider<T>
{
    public abstract T Add(T a, T b);
}

public class FloatMathProvider : MathProvider<float>
{
    public override float Add(float a, float b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

I assumed that math with my wrapper class would be slower than simply adding two floats normally. I am seeing the opposite result. 
When I run the following program, and measure the performance using the `StopWatch` class, it appears that adding 1,000,000 floats is actually faster when using the wrapper class.

```
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var mathProvider = new FloatMathProvider();
        var points = 1000000;

        var dataOne = GenerateRandomFloats(points);
        var dataTwo = GenerateRandomFloats(points);
        var stopwatch_mathProvider = new Stopwatch();
        var stopwatch_native = new Stopwatch();


        stopwatch_mathProvider.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
        {
            var test = dataOne[i] + dataTwo[i];
        }
        stopwatch_mathProvider.Stop();

        stopwatch_native.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
        {
            var test = mathProvider.Add(dataOne[i], dataTwo[i]);
        }
        stopwatch_native.Stop();


        Console.WriteLine("float:\t\t" + stopwatch_native.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("Provider:\t" + stopwatch_mathProvider.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static float[] GenerateRandomFloats(long points)
    {
        var data = new float[points];
        var random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
        {
            data[i] = 100f * (float)random.NextDouble();
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the output in release mode:

```
float:          10182
Provider:       1560
```

and in Debug mode:

```
float:          38717
Provider:       13127
```

This seems to go against intuition. Can someone please explain why addition through a generic wrapper class is faster? Furthermore, what other operations are in general faster when wrapped in a generic class?

Comment: Didn't you just swap the stopwatches or this is a typo here? stopwatch_native seems to be measuring the mathProvider and the stopwatch_mathProvider is measuring the native addition.

Comment: Performance measurments in debug mode are uninteresting; the optimizer is far less aggressive in debug mode. And I hope you are not doing your testing *in the debugger* The CLR knows when it is being debugged!  It can de-optimize the program to help the user in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some coffee, you have swapped `stopwatch_mathProvider` with `stopwatch_native` in the test. An actual result is reverse: the math provider is slower, as you expected.

Comment: Well this post is gonna haunt me for the rest of my life. :( Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Eric You should rely on you intuition a bit more :)